# Submit click not working at first click

Tags: javascript

I have a form with fields that are validated on blur. If they are found to be invalid, underneath the invalid field(s) a div is show, causing the form to expand downwards.

If you correct the fields and click on the submit button the divs are hidden again, and the submit button moves upwards.

My theory is that this causes the click event of the submit to not be registered, is that a correct assumption, and if so, is it possible to solve this other then moving the buttons or the feedback divs around so they don't move the button?

Example code: (click the input text field first, then the button to be sure to trigger the blur)

http://plnkr.co/edit/wsneOizyENlepf8Ffm7q?p=preview

Comment: If you want the bug to be found, show the code (edit :the relevant part).

Comment: It's unlikely that moving fields are the cause of the problem since this is a result of the click event in the first place. It's impossible to tell you what the issue is without seeing your code. Perhaps you're preventing the default action within the submit event? Perhaps you're not calling submit on the form?

Comment: Don't just link to the code, **include** the relevant code here.

Comment: sorry, but the whole code is the example..the function that is not called is allowValidation(), but you need the whole thing imho

Comment: @Maarten When you have such a bug, you must first reduce your code to the minimal code reproducing the problem. SO isn't a remote debugging service.

Comment: even shorter code now in the link

Comment: With your Plunker, I can't reproduce the symptom of the button not working on the first click. What exactly are you experiencing with this? I'm running Chrome 27.0.1453.116.

Comment: It happens on chrome for me; make sure you click the textfield first to make sure a blur will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't that the code is not registering the submit click event from being handled.  Its the button is never being clicked.  It seems to me that Chrome is running the blur event. After the blur event, it attempts to perform a mousedown (eventually leading to a click) at the same coordinates.  Since the blur moved the submit button, nothing happens.

If you keep the submit button in the same spot it will work.
See http://plnkr.co/edit/1emnfeHAzOGDXbcFueLT?p=preview

Comment: true, but that will conflict with the designed UX. Any ideas on how to fix this or do I go back to the UX team?

Comment: It probably won't quite match your UX, but rather than checking the field on blur, check all fields on the focus event.  Apply the function to all form elements except the button. (or set a lastElement variable and check the element it refers to then update it to focused element).

Comment: interesting idea, will think about that. As the real app is in Angular, and I'm doing the validation in directives, with each field being a directive I need to think of how to trigger those validations of the previous directive..straying more and more away from the straight angular validation model